# How to use the interrupt handler in FreeRTOS?

Tags: c, microcontroller, rtos, interrupt

Hi I'm trying to use the [OpenPicus](http://www.openpicus.com/cms/) devKit for a project I am working on and to my understanding the IDE, upon new project creation, creates code that basically utilizes [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/) and OpenPicus libraries.

What I am trying to figure out is how to use interrupts with the FreeRTOS kernel, or through OpenPicus (i dont think this is possible). I have read that the ISRs in FreeRTOS can be specified with the  `__attribute__ ( ( signal ) )` directive but how are they linked to specific interrupts?(uart or even a pin just going high?)

Comment: Cite *where* you have read about `__attribute__((signal))`; it is almost certainly not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupt handling is architecture, and often compiler specific rather than specific to FreeRTOS. FreeRTOS itself only defines what RTOS calls are valid in an ISR.

The OpenPicus hardware uses a PIC24.  The FreeRTOS demo code for PIC24 includes a timer interrupt and serial interrupt examples in `[...]\Demo\PIC24_MPLAB\timertest.c` and `[...]\Demo\PIC24_MPLAB\serial\serial.c` respectively.  The examples use Microchip's PIC24 compiler syntax.  If you are using an alternative compiler, you will need to consult its documentation.